# Tier Price is not showing if the product has special price in magento 1.9.3

Tags: php, magento

**Screenshot of tier price that are not showing:**

[image: screenshot of tier price that are not showing]

Below is the code that I am used to display tier price in listing and product view page

```
$this->getTierPriceHtml()
```

Below is snippet of code that magento used to check tier price in `tierprice.phtml` file.

```
$_product = $this->getProduct();
$_tierPrices = $this->getTierPrices();
$_finalPriceInclTax = $this->helper('tax')->getPrice($_product, $_product->getFinalPrice(), true);

/** @var $_catalogHelper Mage_Catalog_Helper_Data */
$_catalogHelper = Mage::helper('catalog');

$_weeeTaxAmount = Mage::helper('weee')->getAmountForDisplay($_product);
if (Mage::helper('weee')->typeOfDisplay($_product, array(1,2,4))) {
    $_weeeTaxAttributes = Mage::helper('weee')->getProductWeeeAttributesForDisplay($_product);
}
if (count($_tierPrices) > 0):
endif;
```

But I don't understand why it is not showing in listing and view page.

Somebody please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Tier price will be shown only when the tier price is less than the final price.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I find out the reason that why it was not showing.
The Tier price must be less than or equal to special price otherwise magento won't show the tier price..